# How to integrate Sign in with Apple using Firebase on iOS < 13

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-authentication

My code runs correctly on iOS 13 and up, but when run on version of iOS prior to iOS 13, the code breaks.

```
error "NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[UITraitCollection currentTraitCollection]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x2491aeb30"
```

Please advise about my problem.

```swift
@IBAction func btnAppleID(_ sender: Any) {
  if let authUI = FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI() {
    authUI.providers = [FUIOAuth.appleAuthProvider()]
    authUI.delegate = self
            
    let authVC = authUI.authViewController()
    self.present(authVC, animated: true) {
      print("open vc apple sing in")
    }
  }
}
        
func authUI(_ authUI: FUIAuth, didSignInWith authDataResult: AuthDataResult?, error: Error?) {
  if let user = authDataResult?.user {
    print("user \(user.uid) \(user.email)")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sign in with Apple requires iOS 13 - [see Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/implementing_user_authentication_with_sign_in_with_apple). If you want to use it on iOS 12 or earlier, you'll have to implement your own flow [based on Apple's JavaScript SDK](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/sign_in_with_apple_js/incorporating_sign_in_with_apple_into_other_platforms).

Comment: Thank you for answer, but can you help me about how to find out client_id